# I would like to enumerate window classes names

Tags: winapi

I'm getting a memory access violation which i am not able to figure out.

Here is my code

```
// Called by EnumWindows function.
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(
    HWND hwnd,
    LPARAM lParam
) 
{
    TCHAR buf[1024];
    WINDOWINFO pwi;
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, 1024);
    GetWindowInfo(hwnd, &pwi);

    if (GetClassInfoEx(NULL, MAKEINTATOM(pwi.atomWindowType), &wcex)) {

// ************** read AccessViolation wcex.lpszClassName **************
        wsprintf(catbuf, _T("className=%s, top=%d, left=%d, right=%d, bottom=%d\r\n"), wcex.lpszClassName, pwi.rcWindow.top, pwi.rcWindow.left, pwi.rcWindow.right, pwi.rcWindow.bottom);


        OutputDebugString(catbuf);
    }
    return TRUE;
```

What could be causing the access violation?

Comment: why not use debugger ? may be you view that `wcex.lpszClassName` can be atom (not string)

Comment: `lpszClassName` - Pointer to a null-terminated string or is an **atom**. but `%s` accept only null-terminated string. when it is atom - crash exactly here

Comment: I checked lpszClassName in the debugger and it was 0x0000c11f.
Since the high-order byte is 0, it seems to be correct.

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx
>>The atom must be in the low-order word of lpszClassName; the high-order word must be zero.

Comment: use `IS_INTRESOURCE(wcex.lpszClassName)` and if true - use `%x` format. otherwise `%s`

Comment: Although it worked well, I got an enumeration of ATOM values.
So I tried the GetClassName function and got an enumeration of class names.

Comment: Also you forgot to initialize `WNDCLASSEX::cbSize` before calling `GetClassInfoEx()`. E. g. `WNDCLASSEX wcex{ sizeof(wcex) };`. This sets first member, which is `cbSize`, to the size of the structure and zero-initializes the remaining members.

Comment: `WINDOWINFO` also needs its `cbSize` field initialised. Someone needs to learn to RTFM.

Comment: @jonathan Indeed, lol.

Comment: Copy that!:D
>>https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx
cbSize

Type: UINT

The size, in bytes, of this structure. Set this member to sizeof(WNDCLASSEX). Be sure to set this member before calling the GetClassInfoEx function.